# Writing a for loop to a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm using beautifulsoup to scrape reviews. I have the scraping part down and am ready to write my code to a csv file. Looking at many examples online, I am still not understanding how to write to a csv file. My scraping code is

```
for i in range(0,200,5):
    url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g39143-d92240-Reviews-or" + str(i) + "-Hawthorn_Suites_by_Wyndham_Wichita_East-Wichita_Kansas"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
    reviews = soup.find_all('div', 'reviewSelector')
    for r in reviews:
        print("Rating: ", int(r.find('span','ui_bubble_rating')['class'][1].split('_')[1])/10)
        print("Review snipet: ", r.p.text)
```

To write to a csv I tried wrapping my code in the csv.writer method

```
with open('TA-reviews.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for i in range(0,200,5):
    url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g39143-d92240-Reviews-or" + str(i) + "-Hawthorn_Suites_by_Wyndham_Wichita_East-Wichita_Kansas"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
    reviews = soup.find_all('div', 'reviewSelector')
    for r in reviews:
        print("Rating: ", int(r.find('span','ui_bubble_rating')['class'][1].split('_')[1])/10)
        print("Review snipet: ", r.p.text)
        writer.writerow((rating, review))
```

Which returns an error that rating is undefined yet one rating is printed out

Comment: rating in your last line is not defined.  Nowhere in your code are you defining a variable with the name rating.

Comment: check your indentation after the `for i in range(0,200,5):` without indentation this first for loop does not have a body.

Answer (score 1):

> Which returns an error that rating is undefined

Of course `rating` is undefined. Where in your code do you have a statement binding anything to the name `rating` ?

> yet one rating is printed out

what you print out is the expression `int(r.find('span','ui_bubble_rating')['class'][1].split('_')[1])/10`.  This does not define any `rating` variable.

You want:

```
for r in reviews:
    rating = int(r.find('span','ui_bubble_rating')['class'][1].split('_')[1])/10
    review = r.p.text
    writer.writerow((rating, review))
```

Comment: Ah yes it makes sense now. However I am still getting an error :UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 173-177: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @user9270834 this is another question, and one that has been asked dozen times here. The solution depends on your Python version (which you did not specify) and what exactly you get in `r.p.text`.

Comment: I see what you mean. After some time I saw the errors. Thanks for your help.